# Image not loading on mobile device

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, package, kivy

I have an app that includes some images, however when I package for my android phone the images are blank. Right now in my kv file, the images are being loaded from my D drive, so how would I get them to load on my phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide at least the part where you draw your images in your code. From what you said I can only guess what could be the reason.

Possibilties:

**1) You did not package the images correctly when compiling it with buildozer**

**2) Your path is not correct**

**3) You used "\" instead of "/" in your sourc path**

Create a directory for your images in the same directory where your main.py is and put all your pictures inside (e.g. directory name "img"). Then use os in your file to get the path to the directory where your file is and then use "\" instead of "/"

Example:

```
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

Image(source="".join((PROJECT_PATH, "/img/your_img_file.png")), pos=self.pos, size=self.size)
```

Then add your image directory to your spec file before you compile it.

```
# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
source.include_patterns = img/*
```

If it still not works, please provide some of your code to dive deeper into your problem. I hope it helps.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help, Is a directory for my images necessary? Right now they are in the folder with my main.py and kv file. Currently, I use `Image:   
     source: 'D:/A_Python/master1/circ10.png'`. Would this method of using images cause problems when I package for android? (With correct indentation)

Comment: I have not tried to package it like this, but in general it should not be a problem. The question is rather why you should not put them into a directory. WIth small projects and less images it is not a problem but if your project starts to grow it can get quite confusing when your files are not ordered in a structural way. I always use a directory structure even if my project is a small one (e.g. folders: assets, images, screens, kv_files and and a settings file where I define Variables like the path, colors and so on).

Comment: Programming is not only the coding part but also and mainly the part where you have to give your project a structure for easy readability and a simplicity to expand your project later on. It is a good approach to train that on small projects.

Comment: I've tried using the directory but I think I'm using it wrong, what do you mean by "real path". Thanks for all your help

Comment: If you use it with the absolute path like in my example it should work. Can you show me your code? Did you get an error?

Answer (score 0):

Include the images during the packaging and then load them using a file path relative to your main.py.